# Pandas create a new column with complex condition of multiple other columns

Tags: python, pandas

a df here:

`df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-23', '2020-02-22', '2020-03-04'],  'ID':[1001,1002,1002,1003]})`

I need a table with extra column `Wed`, that gives me last Wednesday of `Date`, and if `ID` is `1002`, returns 2 Wednesday before that `Date`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pd.offsets.Week() can come handy for this problem.

**Solution**

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df['Wed'] = np.where(df.ID == 1002,
         df.Date - pd.offsets.Week(3, weekday=2),
         df.Date - pd.offsets.Week(weekday=2))
```

**Output**

```
    Date         ID       Wed
0   2020-01-01  1001    2019-12-25
1   2020-01-23  1002    2020-01-08
2   2020-02-22  1002    2020-02-05
3   2020-03-04  1003    2020-02-26
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset

d1 = DateOffset(days=7)
d2 = DateOffset(weekday=2)

df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df["Wed"] = np.where(df.ID == 1002, df.Date - 3 * d1 + d2, df.Date - d1 + d2)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        Date    ID        Wed
0 2020-01-01  1001 2019-12-25
1 2020-01-23  1002 2020-01-08
2 2020-02-22  1002 2020-02-05
3 2020-03-04  1003 2020-02-26
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `freq` argument in [pandas.date_range()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) to `W-WED` to generate a list of Wednesday date range.

```py
def get_wed(row):
    return pd.date_range(end=row['Date'], periods=(3 if row['ID'] == 1002 else 2), freq='W-WED')[0]

df['Wed'] = df.apply(get_wed, axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

        Date    ID        Wed
0 2020-01-01  1001 2019-12-25
1 2020-01-23  1002 2020-01-08
2 2020-02-22  1002 2020-02-05
3 2020-03-04  1003 2020-02-26
```